# How do you link to a different part of your website in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap button. When the button is clicked I want it to link to another page. I created a page called bitcoin.html. How do I link the contents of my main page to my bitcoin.html page. Anchor tags seem to create a hyperlink inside the bootstrap button - I don't want that. I created an onclick function and tried to redirect it. But it isn't working.

```js
function relocate {

  location.href = "CRYPTOAPP/bitcoin.html"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cryptocurrency App</title>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <h1>Cryptos To Watch 2022</h1>
  <div class="container" id="crypocontainer">

      <div class="card bitcoin" id="bitcoin">
        <h1> Bitcoin </h1>
        <img src="images/bitcoin.png" alt="bitcoin image">
        <h2>Current Price </h2>
        <h3 class="btc"> Btc</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="relocate_bitcoin">Explore</button>
      </div>
</body>
```

[image: File directory]

Comment: Why aren't you using an anchor link? That's what they're for. Buttons aren't for navigation.

Comment: Don't use a `button` or some other JS hack for this. Page transfers should be done with `<a>` elements for both accessibility and graceful degradation.

Comment: the anchor tag changed the bootstrap button to a blue hyperlink. Which negated the styling. I wanted the bootstrap styling to remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is called `relocate` but you're trying to call `relocate_bitcoin` in your onclick event. You also need to actually call the function, i.e. `relocate()`.

That said, you don't need a function for this—you can put that directly in the onclick:

`onclick="location.href='CRYPTOAPP/bitcoin.html';"`